# How to set a EditText that popup a calender to select date and display in EditText in Tab Activity

Tags: android, tabs, calendar, android-edittext, onclicklistener

How to set a EditText that popup a calender to select date and display in EditText  in Tab Activity.

My Tab activity as below.  I need the code to post before the return V.

Here the tab activity

```
package com.artificers.subin.inspection;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Subin on 13-10-2015.
 */
public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_view, container, false);

        return V;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Start from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display a `DatePicker` dialog and `onDateSet` listener like so:

```
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public void displayDatePicker() {
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener =
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Tab3Fragment.this.year = year;
                        Tab3Fragment.this.month = monthOfYear;
                        Tab3Fragment.this.day = dayOfMonth;
                        updateDisplay();
                    }
                };
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        // update your EditText here
    }
```

Just call `displayDatePicker` when you would like the user to pick a date and format a date `String` to go into your `EditText` in the `updateDisplay` method. Hope this helps.

**EDIT: Implemented with your code as requested**

```
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_view, container, false);
            displayDatePicker();
            return V;
        }
    }


    public void displayDatePicker() {
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener =
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Tab3Fragment.this.year = year;
                        Tab3Fragment.this.month = monthOfYear;
                        Tab3Fragment.this.day = dayOfMonth;
                        updateDisplay();
                    }
                };
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        // update your EditText here
    }
```

I cannot fill out the `updateDisplay` method for you as I don't know what your `EditText` is called or how it is set up in your layout.

Comment: I need the code to post before the return V. I only the above code only ,                        new to the android .pls help me

Comment: Edited, I can't offer you any more information with the code you have provided, it seems you would be better off looking at some coding tutorials or books instead of posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please post your error, has your project only started crashing since inputting the above code? Also post your new code. Thanks.

Comment: Whoops! Left in my own Fragment. I've now edited it to be yours. :-)

Comment: I am so thankful for the time you took to help with my project.@vguzzi

Comment: No worries! Hope it goes well.